# How to get from local storage when key is crazy

Tags: javascript, local-storage, azure-ad-msal

Problem: Library is giving me tokens with long keys. I need the value of a key(refresh-token) so I can make an api request with this token in the headers

Msal is storing tokens to my localstorage with a crazy string, multiple of them. 1 accesstoken, 1 refresh token and a tokenId. I just need to get the refresh token value.. but the key is 35eef60c-0000-0000-0000-20cd77000000.bf390000-0000-0000-0000-528094e00000-login.windows.net-refreshtoken-00000000-0000-0000-bf00-000000000003----
How would I attempt to get this value when the key changes its string and is so long?

Comment: Can you please specify better what is the problem?

Comment: I dont really know how to phrase this. I am just using Oauth flow and after signin, this library is giving me tokens in my local storage. I just dont know how to target the token I need to get the value of the refresh token. Normally, I would just localstorage.getItem('key'). But since this is changing, I cannot go that route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys(localStorage)` to get all of the values within localStorage, then proceed to loop over all of them and grab the value for each one.

```js
const keys = Object.keys(localStorage);

const storageMap = keys.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = localStorage.getItem(curr);
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(storageMap)
```